Getting grid, magnetic, and true north declination in QGIS
I have been following a guide for making topo maps in QGIS and it has been extremely informative and helpful however it seems to have used an older version as at the end the calculation for the declination of the grid does not seem to work. I have used the Lat Long tools plugin to get the coords of the rough centre of my map and used https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml to calculate the true north declination however when I try to use the below to calculate the map grid declination it doesn't work. Instead it just prints the literal text on my layout.
[%with_variable(’GtT’,
-with_variable(’raw_GtT’,
with_variable(’PT’,
    transform(centroid(item_variables(’Map 1’)[’map_extent’]),
        @project_crs,’EPSG:4326’),
    with_variable(’displacedPT’,translate(@PT,0,0.001),
    azimuth(centroid(item_variables(’Map 1’)[’map_extent’]),
    transform(@displacedPT,’EPSG:4326’,@project_crs))
))/pi()*180.0,
if(@raw_GtT > 180, ’-’ || (360-@raw_GtT), @raw_GtT)),
if(@GtT > 0, ’+’, ’-’) || format_number(@GtT, 1) || ’ degrees’
)%]

As Andrea Giudiceandrea pointed out the code was syntactically incorrect, addressing the syntax issues addressed the literal text printing issue however it seems there is an issue with the code itself as it is now printing --123.0 degrees for a region with a calculated magnetic declination of -12.03 degrees.
New Code:
[%with_variable('GtT',
-with_variable('raw_GtT',
with_variable('PT',
    transform(centroid(item_variables('Map 1')['map_extent']),
        @project_crs,'EPSG:4326'),
    with_variable('displacedPT',translate(@PT,0,0.001),
    azimuth(centroid(item_variables('Map 1')['map_extent']),
    transform(@displacedPT,'ESPG:4326',@project_crs))
))/pi()*180.0,
if(@raw_GtT > 180, '-' || (360-@raw_GtT), @raw_GtT)),
if(@GtG > 0, '+', '-') || format_number(@GtT, 1) || ' degrees'
)%]


Have you tried subsets of your expression to debug first?  Like azimuth(the centroid, transform(the displaced centroid)), without the variables

First of all, the expression is syntactically wrong: you are incorrectly using the ´ "Acute Accent" / "tick" character (Unicode U+00B4) instead of the proper character that is the ' "Apostrophe" / "single quote" character (Unicode U+0027).
Ref: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#writing-an-expression.
UPDATE:
Moreover, the expression contains a logical flaw where it incorrectly adds an additional leading "minus sign" to a negative number to be displayed resulting in two leading "minus signs" for negative numbers.
To fix such issue, you need to replace the if(@GtT > 0, '+', '-') part with if(@GtT > 0, '+', '').
Anyway, such expression cannot calculate the magnetic declination: it looks like you are mixing up the concepts of grid convergence and magnetic declination. You cannot use the "Magnetic Field Calculators" tool at https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml, which computes the magnetic declination, to check the correctness of the value returned by the expression, which allegedly computes the grid convergence angle.

Thank you for pointing out the syntax error, I should have checked that after copying from a PDF. I no longer get the raw code printed out anymore, however I am getting a weird output. I've calculated that the magnetic north declination should be approx -12.03 degrees but this code is producing --123.0 degrees.

@OpticalMagician, please provide a link to the PDF where you have copied the expression from. Moreover, such expression cannot calculate the magnetic declination: you are mixing up the concept of grid convergence with the concept of magnetic declination. You cannot use the tool at https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml, which compute the magnetic declination to check the correctness of the value returned by the expression.

@OpticalMagician, see the updated answer.
